# Rotate image and save in React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native, image-rotation, rn-fetch-blob

I am going to rotate the image in react–native and I would like to get base64 of rotated image.
I used several libraries

1. `react-native-image-rotate`: It's working well on Android but on iOS I get `rct-image-store://1` as url so I tried getting base64 using `rn-fetch-blob` but it throws error that can't recognize that url.
2. `react-native-image-resizer`: I used this but the response is not good in iOS. If I set -90 then rotate -180, if I set -180 then it's rotating as -270.

Please help me on this problem, how can I rotate the image in iOS.

I need to rotate the image as -90, -180, -270, -360(original).

Comment: You can view the rotated image

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found answer.

```
import ImageRotate from 'react-native-image-rotate';
import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer';
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

ImageRotate.rotateImage(
        this.state.image.uri,
        rotateDegree,
        uri => {
          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            console.log('rotate', uri);
            RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(uri, 'base64').then(data => {
              const object = {};
              object.base64 = data;
              object.width = this.state.image.height;
              object.height = this.state.image.width;
              object.uri = uri;
              this.setState({image: object, spinner: false});
            });
          } else {
            console.log(uri);
            const outputPath = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir}`;

            ImageResizer.createResizedImage(
              uri,
              this.state.image.height,
              this.state.image.width,
              'JPEG',
              100,
              0,
              outputPath,
            ).then(response => {
              console.log(response.uri, response.size);
              let imageUri = response.uri;
              if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                imageUri = imageUri.split('file://')[1];
              }
              RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(imageUri, 'base64').then(resData => {
                const object = {};
                object.base64 = resData;
                object.width = this.state.image.height;
                object.height = this.state.image.width;
                object.uri = response.uri;
                this.setState({image: object, spinner: false});
              });
            });
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);
        },
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my work well code up to now

```
  rotateImage = (angle) => {
    const { currentImage } = this.state; // origin Image, you can pass it from params,... as you wish
    ImageRotate.rotateImage( // using 'react-native-image-rotate'
      currentImage.uri,
      angle,
      (rotatedUri) => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          ImageStore.getBase64ForTag( // import from react-native 
            rotatedUri,
            (base64Image) => {
              const imagePath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${new Date().getTime()}.jpg`;
              RNFS.writeFile(imagePath, `${base64Image}`, 'base64') // using 'react-native-fs'
                .then(() => {
                  // now your file path is imagePath (which is a real path)
                  if (success) {
                    this.updateCurrentImage(imagePath, currentImage.height, currentImage.width);
                    ImageStore.removeImageForTag(rotatedUri);
                  }
                })
                .catch(() => {});
            },
            () => {},
          );
        } else {
          this.updateCurrentImage(rotatedUri, currentImage.height, currentImage.width);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
    );
  };
```

I think you have done `rotatedUri`.

- Then you can get base64 by `ImageStore` from `react-native`.
- Then write it to the local image with `react-native-fs`

After that you have `imagePath` is the local image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I checked imagestore before, But it is already deprecated and now I can't use it.

Comment: I check it and you're right. The issue can be found here https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/675

Comment: Yes, what's is the solution?

Comment: The issue is open. So maybe no solution at this time.

Comment: Hi tuledev, I can get rct-image-store url image with ImageResizer.createResizedImage

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Expo Image Manipulator
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/

```
  const rotated = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
    image.uri,
    [{ rotate: -90 }],
    { base64: true }
  );
```